# Problem with shopping cart, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have built a simple shopping cart. The problem is that the first time i try to add an item nothing happens. If i click the buy button a second time an item is added.
What is the cause if this problem?

Thanx!

.aspx

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="main" runat="server">
White lily
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" OnClick="buy_Click" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="rightBar" runat="server">
    <UserControl:ShoppingCart id="shoppingCart" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

.ascx

```
public partial class UserControls_ShoppingCart : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private List<Flower> FlowerList 
    {
        get
        {
            List<Flower> tmp = Session["FlowerList"] as List<Flower>;
            if (tmp == null)
            {
                tmp = new List<Flower>();
            }
            return tmp;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FillRepeater();
        }

    }

    public void ShoppingCart_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item != null)
        {
            Label itemLabel = e.Item.FindControl("itemLabel") as Label;
            Flower flower = e.Item.DataItem as Flower;
            if (flower != null)
            {
                itemLabel.Text = flower.getName(flower);
            }
        }
    }

    private void FillRepeater()
    {
        shoppingCartRepeater.DataSource = FlowerList;
        shoppingCartRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    public void AddFlower(Flower flower)
    {
        FlowerList.Add(flower);
        Session["FlowerList"] = FlowerList;
        FillRepeater();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a method for you `buy_Click` click event. Can you post that from your *.aspx.cs

Comment: Are you sure that it can convert the data from the session to the list object and vice versa correctly? I wouldn't trust that and rather choose a different way for the temporary data storage. Why don't you just create an object just for that purpose in you custom control declaration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pursuant to my comment on the first answer.. try this

```
 private List<Flower> FlowerList 
    {
        get
        {
             return(_FlowerList);
        }
        set
        {
            _FlowerList = value;
        }

    }
    protected List<Flower> _FlowerList = new FlowerList();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (Session["FlowerList"]!= null) {
           FlowerList = (List<Flower>)Session["FlowerList"];
       }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FillRepeater();
        }
    }
```

It should work with everything else the same. A better way would be to use ViewState though, and save the value of _FlowerList in SaveViewState()

Comment: Big thank you jamietre, your solution worked fine. The only thing i needed to change was (FlowerList)Session["FlowerList"] to (List<Flower>)Session["FlowerList"]

Comment: Ah, the risks of writing (but not running) code. Fixed in the response, glad it helped.

Comment: interesting, it's kinda the opposite of lazy loading creating the object everytime only to be stored in session when its not there. i suppose the 'inefficiency' is negligible here

Comment: @gabriel, i can't disagree with you, it was not well thought except to the extent of "will it work." It would be better to add logic in the "get" to check _FlowerList for a value first, if null then load the session value (if available), and finally create a new object if none of the above. Or I guess just check for null in the get and leave the Session in page load? Anyway... details...

Comment: @jamietre, +1 I totally respect the 'get it to work' attitude.

Comment: Big thanx to all that helped me with this one!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm guessing here based on skimming the code, so I might be wrong but maybe the first time around it's not a postback and FillRepeater does not get called.

Comment: Was thinking the same thing but he calls FillRepeater in AddFlower. I think it has something to do with the weird FlowerList property/session object.

Comment: Gabriel, i tryed to remove if (!Page.IsPostBack) but the problem remains.

Comment: I am surprised I'm not sure if this is the case, but when you assign a Session variable is it immediately available for reading? I think maybe not. So the first time you add a Flower, then assign it to the Session["FlowerList"], FillRepeater will not know about it - the property will return a new FlowerList. After the 2nd postback it will contain the value it got before, though. This would explain it. You should not use Session to keep values during a given page execution. Add a "get" property and store the object in a private object as well.